# print data with auto increment in paging

Tags: php, mysql

i know it's a silly question, but it is creating a problem for me....
I want to print data from mysql with auto increment, but when i use the below code, it auto increments the value in the same page but i want it to be continued to the next pages also, here is my code

```
<?php
$perpage = 10; 
$start = (isset($_GET['id'])) ? $_GET['id'] : 0;
$TotalRec = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM register where
r_bid='".$_SESSION["id"]."'"), 0);
$select = "SELECT * FROM register where r_bid='".$_SESSION["id"]."' LIMIT 
$start,$perpage";
$result = mysql_query($select) or die(mysql_error());
$res = mysql_query("select * from regi_balic where b_id='".$_SESSION["id"]."'");
$row1=mysql_fetch_array($res);
$i=1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{   
echo '<tr>
<td align="center" width=5%><font size=3>'.$i.'</font></td>
<td width=12%><font size=3>'.$row1['name'].'</font></td>
<td align="center" width=5%><font size=3><a href="edit_detail.phpid='.$row["r_id"].'
&cand_id='.$_SESSION["id"].'&email='.$row["email"].'">'.$row['name'].'</a></font></td>
<td align="center" width=5%><font size=3>'.$row['reference'].'</font></td>
<td align="right" style="padding-right:8px" width=12%>
<fontsize=3>'.$row['age'].'</font></td>
<td align="right" style="padding-right:8px"  width=12%>
<fontsize=3>'.$row['occupation'].'</font></td>
<td width=12%><font size=3>'.$row['mob_no'].'</font></td>
<td width=2%><a href="process_del_client.php?id='.$row['r_id'].'" 
onClick="returnConfirmSubmit(\'Are You sure ?\')"><img src = "images/delete.png">
</a></td>
</tr>';
}
$i++;
echo '</table>';
if($start == 0)
{
echo "<br>Previous Page&nbsp;";
}
else
{
echo '<br><a href='."./view.php?id=" . ($start - $perpage) . '>'.
"PreviousPage".'</a>&nbsp;';
}
if($start + $perpage >= $TotalRec)
{
echo "&nbsp;Next Page<br>";
}
else
{
echo '&nbsp;<a href='."./view.php?id=" . ($start + $perpage) . '>'."Next Page".'
</a><br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: you can read the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql

Comment: ... and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update value in a session variable and use that onto another page for updation .
Ex..

$_SESSION['value']=0
$_SESSION['value']=$_SESSION['value']++;

Comment: it is always taking the same value after only 1 increment i.e. 1

Comment: but if you change your value in session variable then this won't be the same , you just need to write ..

start_session(); in php code .in all the pages where you want to access the variable's value as well as on same  page where you are changing the value of session varible..

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
$i=1;
```

to

```
$i=1+$start;
```